# How to install a plugin using JRuby?

Tags: plugins, jqgrid, jruby

I'm trying to install the jQuery Grid Rails Plugin. I'm using JRuby 1.7.0. I tried this command with no luck:

```
jruby -S plugin install git://github.com/ahe/2dc_jqgrid.git
rails plugin install git://github.com/ahe/2dc_jqgrid.git
```

And some others...

I know that some commands change for JRuby. Commonly I prepend `jruby -S` to the command but it's not working with plugin install. Any suggestion?

Regards.

Comment: >jruby -S plugin install git://github.com/ahe/2dc_jqgrid.git 
jruby: No such file or directory -- plugin (LoadError)

All the times it says jruby: No such file or directory -- plugin (LoadError), and if I use the rails command directly it says it's not recognized, it's ok considering I'm using JRuby

Comment: try `jruby -S rails plugin install git://github.com/ahe/2dc_jqgrid.git`

Comment: No such file or directory -- rails (LoadError)

Comment: How did you create your rails project if you cannot run rails command?You should have rails binary in `$JRUBY_HOME/bin` if you install rails correctly. Try to reinstall rails `gem install rails`.

Comment: I create my project ussing Netbeans... :| but from command line I do can start my server: jruby script/rails server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was executing the command `jruby -S plugin install git://github.com/ahe/2dc_jqgrid.git`

The error message says:

```
jruby: No such **file or directory** -- plugin (LoadError)
```

As you may know there is a rails file under the ../script folder, since the error says *No such file or directory* I thought of pointing jruby into the right directory and file:

```
jruby script/rails plugin install git://github.com/ahe/2dc_jqgrid.git
```

That way jruby knows where is the script that I need. This should work the same way for the other rails commands as generate and server.